# Javascript problem when setting src for img element in FireFox - string parsing error?

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, src, prefetch

I'm having problems with image's on the page.  I'm using Javascript to create the elements, and in FireFox it seems the string that I'm using to set the innerHTML is not being parsed correctly.  I'll see this when the server page is requested with invalid GET variables.  They look like this (from the PHP script's error handler):

> ```
> GET[] = Array
> (
>   [shrink] => true
>   [file_id] => \'   file_id   \'
>   [refresh] => \'   now.getTime()   \'
> )
> ```

This only happens for about 5% of requests, which is making it difficult to solve.  I have been able to reproduce this myself in FireFox, and Firebug will show that the URL it is trying to fetch is: https://www.domain.com/secure/%27%20+%20image_src%20+%20%27

I read somewhere that it might be related to FireFox prefetching content (can't find it googling now), since it seems to only happen on FireFox.  Disabling prefetching in about:config **does** prevent the problem from occurring, but I'm looking for another solution or workaround that doesn't involve end users changing their configurations.

Here's the specifics and code:
I have an empty table cell on an HTML page.  In JQuery's $(document).ready() function for the page, I used JQuery's $.ajax() method to get some data from the server about what should be in that cell.  It returns the `file_id` variable, which for simplicity I just set below.  It then sets the empty table cell to have an image with src that points to a page that will serve the image file depending on what file_id is passed.  This part of the code was JQuery originally, so I changed it to straight Javascript but that didn't help anything.

```
//get data about image from server
//this is actually done through JQuery's $.ajax() but you get the idea
var file_id = 12;

//create the src for the img
//the refresh is to prevent the image from being cached ever, since the page's
//javascript will be it changes
//during the course of the page's life
var now = new Date();
var image_src = 'serve_image.php?shrink=true&file_id=' + file_id + '&refresh=' + now.getTime();

//create 
document.getElementById('image_cell').innerHTML =
    '<A target="_blank" href="serve_image.php?file_id=' + file_id + '">' +
        '<IMG id=image_element src="' + image_src + '" alt="Loading...">' + 
    '</A>';`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Wayyy to much reading...

Comment: What exactly do the real "file_id" values look like?

Comment: They are integers, usually in the range of 500 - 1500.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output HTML? Or does it give you an error and doesn't load the page?

Comment: The page loads fine.  And even when I've been able to reproduce the error the image appears to load fine.  There haven't been any complaints by users, and I've never noticed the problem when using or testing the page myself.

It seems to me like there's some kind of bug in FireFox's prefetching of images that results in the Javascript string getting parsed incorrectly, and it trying to prefetch a URL with the wrong values.

It sounds far-fetched, but I can't figure out what else might be going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `document.getElementById("image_cell").innerHTML`, try giving your <a> an ID and doing

```
document.getElementById('a_tag_id_here').href = 'serve_image.php?file_id=' + file_id;
document.getElementById('image_element').src = image_src;
```

If you can't set the anchor tag's id, there are other DOM functions that make it easy to get to. The point is, I think changing innerHTML is the source of your problem.

Comment: If you don't have these elements before fetching the image data via ajax, you could make placeholder objects server-side, or use DOM methods to create them. In this case, I suggest using methods involving new Image() rather than document.createElement('img') for cross-browser compatibility (I've had issues with IE and creating img tags. If you need further info I can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing double and single quotes.  Since your code example is modified, I can't be sure, but my guess is that this line:

```
var image_src = 'serve_image.php?shrink=true&file_id=' + file_id + '&refresh=' + now.getTime();
```

is really being treated like this:

```
var image_src = "'serve_image.php?shrink=true&file_id=' + file_id + '&refresh=' + now.getTime()";
```

Is your JavaScript being generated by PHP, or is it in a separate file?  If you're outputting the JavaScript inline, you may want to consider putting it in a separate *.js file to reduce the liklihood that PHP's treatment of quotes is not interfering with the JavaScript quotes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  Yeah, I assumed I just made a mistake with quotes since that's what it looks like.  But remember that this is only happening in about 5% of the page requests.  It takes a few minutes of reloading the page constantly to reproduce the error.  If if it were just a typo bug this would be happening at each page request.

Comment: I originally found the error because there would be an error log entry from serve_image.php every few days, even though the page is being used much more frequently than that.